# Wordpress widget defaults are saved but the display won't change values

Tags: wordpress

I made this plugin [yelp reviews ticker](http://wordpress.org/plugins/yelp-reviews-ticker/)

 My problem is in the admin interface when you change the values such as: (anything that involves text)

- Widget Title
- Speed
- Pause
  -

They get saved and everything works great, only when those values are changed to "0" they get saved to the db but on the admin interface for the widget the default value shows up.

So I don't have a bug displaying the widget at all, it just won't show  "0" when that is set.

Anyone has an idea of how to fix that?


Here is the portion of the code (I've only posted the part that I have problems with)

```
    function form( $instance ) { //<- set default parameters of widget
$title = empty($instance['title']) ? Reviews : $instance['title'];
$speed = empty($instance['speed']) ? 2500 : $instance['speed'];
$pause = empty($instance['pause']) ? 6000 : $instance['pause'];
~~~~~~~~~

?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title');?>">Widget Title</label><br />
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('speed');?>">Speed</label><br />
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('speed');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('speed');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $speed; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pause');?>">Pause</label><br />
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pause');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('pause');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $pause; ?>"/>
    </p>
```

I think the main problem is within these lines

```
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? Reviews : $instance['title'];
$speed = empty($instance['speed']) ? 2500 : $instance['speed'];
$pause = empty($instance['pause']) ? 6000 : $instance['pause'];
```

Thanks!

Comment: If more than one "0" is used ie "00" it will display that value... why is it that a single "0" won't be used as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was this:

```
'' == NULL = true
0 == NULL = true
false == NULL = true
```

So:

```
$speed = empty($instance['speed']) ? 2500 : $instance['speed'];
```

With a single zero will come back "true"

 meaning it will use the "2500" value.
I changed the code to "isset" wich fixed it

```
if (isset($instance['speed'])) {
    $speed = $instance['speed'];
} else {
    $speed = "2500"; //default
}
```

Solved it, thanks